# How to add click event listener to Nav.Link in React Bootstrap?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-bootstrap

```js
return (

            <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
                <Navbar.Brand href="/">Instagram</Navbar.Brand>
                <Nav className="mr-auto">
                    <Nav.Link href="/">main</Nav.Link>
                    <Nav.Link><a onClick={logoutHandler}>logout</a></Nav.Link>
                </Nav>
                <Form inline>
                    <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                    <Button variant="outline-info">Search</Button>
                </Form>
            </Navbar>
        )
```

I want to add onclick event on <Nav.Link>. like I do on my code.. but it didn't work. How do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the docs I think you might be able to use `onSelect`: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navs/#nav-link-props

```
return (
    <Navbar bg="dark" variant="dark">
            <Navbar.Brand href="/">Instagram</Navbar.Brand>
            <Nav className="mr-auto">
                <Nav.Link href="/">main</Nav.Link>
                <Nav.Link onSelect={logoutHandler}>logout</Nav.Link>
            </Nav>
            <Form inline>
                <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
                <Button variant="outline-info">Search</Button>
            </Form>
        </Navbar>
    );
```

Comment: I can't make it work nowdays. Probably `onSelect` is moved from `Nav.Link` to `Nav`. It works this way now: `<Nav onSelect={handleSelect}>` with child `<Nav.Link eventKey="1">` where `const handleSelect = (eventKey) => alert(\`selected ${eventKey}\`);`. Taken from here: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/docs/components/navs/#navlink